# Paypal says look at the next page, before paying - but then it is directly payed

Tags: paypal, checkout

we have integrated ExpressCheckout into our Website. Now we have the problem that at a page after the login paypal says (translated): Please review this information. On the next page you can send the payment. But if you click on the next button, there is no next page. The payment is directly sent. What goes wrong here?

lg Manu

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could not send the true fields to paypal, following variables as ;

```
$item_name      = $product->model;
$item_number        = $order['id'];
$item_amount        = str_replace(',','.', format_number($calculate['total_price']));

# than account information of paypal

$paypal_inf = $paypal_->row();                      $paypal_email   = $paypal_inf->paypal_key;
$paypal_value   = $paypal_inf->paypal_value;

# Url information
$return_url = base_url().'tr/odeme/adim_5/paypalsuccess';
$cancel_url = base_url().'tr/odeme/adim_5/paypalfailed';
$notify_url = base_url().'tr/odeme/adim_5/paypal';

# Firstly Append paypal account to querystring
$querystring = "?business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";

# adding information of following variables at top as you can see
$querystring .= "item_number=".urlencode($item_number)."&";
$querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($item_name)."&";
$querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($item_amount)."&";

# loop for posted values and append to querystring (as address,phone or more detailed informaation)

foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$querystring .= "$key=$value&";
}

// Append paypal return addresses
$querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
$querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
$querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);

# And

redirect('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'. $querystring, 'location', 301);
```

add some fields to form side, following line will receive that

```
echo form_hidden('cmd','_xclick');
echo form_hidden('no_note','1');
echo form_hidden('lc','TR');
echo form_hidden('currency_code',$exchange);
echo form_hidden('bn','PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest');
```

if you are using auto redirect, this will help (add your button id which you created on paypal)

```
echo form_hidden('cmd','_s-xclick');
echo form_hidden('hosted_button_id',$paypal_button_id); // for ex. FK5RYJS6WRJVL
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

sorry don't get exactly what you mean?! Or where the problem is located... My Query looks like...

```
// Build URL with all infos
        $nvpstr = '&AMT=' . $amt .
                  '&ITEMAMT=' . $amt .
                  '&CURRENCYCODE=' . $this->currencyCode .
                  '&LOCALECODE=' . $user->land .
                  '&PAYMENTACTION=' . $this->paymentAction .
                  '&RETURNURL=' . $returnUrl .
                  '&CANCELURL=' . $cancelUrl .
                  '&DESC=' . $this->getDesc() .
                  '&SHIPTONAME=' . $user->vorname . ' ' . $user->nachname .
                  '&SHIPTOSTREET=' . $user->strasse .
                  '&SHIPTOCITY=' . $user->ort .
                  '&SHIPTOZIP=' . $user->plz .
                  '&L_NAME0=www.detailpool.com' .
                  '&L_AMT0=' . $amt .
                  '&NOSHIPPING=1' .
                  '&USERACTION=commit';
        //echo $nvpstr; die();

        $this->callerService = new CallerService($this->type, $this->test);
        $resArray = $this->callerService->hash_call("SetExpressCheckout", $nvpstr);


            header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=' . $resArray['TOKEN']);
        }
```

And then

```
/**
     * Wird nach der Rückkehr von Paypal aufgerufen
     */
    public function getCheckoutDetails($amt) {
        $this->writeLog("Paypal Status-Update started...", 1);

        $token = JRequest::getVar('token', 0);
        $this->group = JRequest::getInt('group', -1);
        $this->type = JRequest::getInt('type', -1);
        $amt = round($amt, 2);

        // Build URL with all infos
        $nvpstr = '&TOKEN=' . urlencode($token) .
                  '&NOSHIPPING=1' .
                  '&USERACTION=commit';

        $this->callerService = new CallerService($this->type, $this->test);
        $resArray = $this->callerService->hash_call("GetExpressCheckoutDetails", $nvpstr);

        $this->completeSale($resArray['TOKEN'], $resArray['PAYERID'], $amt);
    }

    /**
     * Nach der Abwicklung auf der Paypalseite wird eine weitere Aktion erforderlich,
     * um die Kaufabwicklung zu bestätigen...
     */
    private function completeSale($token, $payerID, $amt) {
        require_once(JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_detailpool/libraries/Zahlung.php');

        // Build URL with all infos
        $nvpstr = '&TOKEN=' . urlencode($token) .
                  '&PAYERID=' . urlencode($payerID) .
                  '&PAYMENTACTION=' . $this->paymentAction .
                  '&AMT=' . $amt .
                  '&CURRENCYCODE=' . $this->currencyCode .
                  '&DESC=' . $this->getDesc();

        $resArray = $this->callerService->hash_call("DoExpressCheckoutPayment", $nvpstr);

        $this->writeLog('DoExpressCheckoutPayment Amt: ' . $amt . ' Group: ' . $this->group);

        // Prüfen, ob alles geklappt hat
        if ($resArray['PAYMENTSTATUS'] == 'Completed') {
            return $this->paymentSuccess();
        }
        else {
            $this->paymentFail();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any problem on queries, but try to add urlencode() as,

```
$querystring .= "item_number=".urlencode($item_number)."&";
```

instead of

```
 '&CURRENCYCODE=' . $this->currencyCode .
```

Comment: sorry, that didn't work, same problem as before! Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is solved. Paypal redirects to the shop site and the aim is, that the user can confirm the payment on the shop site. Not on paypal. lg